# How to convert a stored procedure which has a user-defined table type as a parameter and called recursively from MS SQL Server to MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-migration

I'm converting a stored procedure from MS SQL Server to MySQL 8.
And the stored procedure has a user-defined table type and it has a recursive call to the same one like the following structure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_RECURSIVE_WITH_TABLE_AS_PARAMETER]
   @CUSTOM_TABLE_TYPE CUSTOM_TABLE READONLY
AS
BEGIN
-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   EXECUTE [dbo].[SP_RECURSIVE_WITH_TABLE_AS_PARAMETER] @CUSTOM_TABLE=@CUSTOM_TABLE

-- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: Can you post a running example -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017 so we can see what it does?  This code is way to minimal to give suggestions/answer for that matter.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Raymond Nijland, but I cannot share a working example, because it is part of a big database.

Comment: *"but I cannot share a working example,"* Then we simply can't help you see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> "Help others reproduce the problem" ... "because it is part of a big database." Consider hiring a DBA with SQL Server (MSSQL) and MySQL knowledge